# ERROR:offline js file is empty

Tags: react-native

hai in my react native project structure is like this:

```
Project
   •     Ios
        •   Project
            •   Base.Iproj
            •   Images.xcassets
            •   AppDelegate.h
            •   AppDelegate.m
            •   Info.plist
            •   Main.jsbundle
            •   Main.m
       •    Project.xcodeproj
       •    ProjectTests
   •   Index.ios.js
   •   Package.json
```

when i need to run i ma getting error like this Error:Offline js file is empty. see ios/main.jsbundle for instructions
but the main.jsbundile file is in  ios/Project/main.jsbundle,
can any one help me how to avoid this error

Comment: It sounds like you have a linking issue in your xcode project. When you hit command+B in the project does your build fail?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a linking problem. This is a problem with the `main.jsbundle` in your iOS application project folder not updating. If you open the existing `main.jsbundle` it just throws an error, which is what you're seeing on your device.

To fix this create a new `main.jsbundle`.

1. From your React project's root (`/Project`), run the following command in a Terminal shell: `react-native bundle --minify`. If run successfully it will create a new `main.jsbundle` and drop it in `/Project/iOS/`.
2. Replace the existing main.jsbundle in `/Project/iOS/Project` with the one created in `/Project/iOS/`

(Having to do this manually is frustrating and should be automated, or fixed within the React Native script)

Clean, build and re-run the app and it should load on the device.

More from FB on how to run your app on a device:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html